# How to prevent including everything into one file?

Tags: php, slim

I'm going to use [Slim Framework](http://docs.slimframework.com/#GET-Routes). The, it seems that it is going to be everything in one single file. I don't want PHP to compile everything. How can I split them?

For example I have

```
$app->get('/articles/:id', function ($id) use ($app) { })
$app->get('/profiles/:id', function ($id) use ($app) { })
$app->get('/messages/:id', function ($id) use ($app) { })
$app->get('/articles', function ($id) use ($app) { })
$app->get('/search/:foo', function ($id) use ($app) { })
$app->delete('/message/:id', function ($id) use ($app) { })
```

Should I put `include` into `{}` so that only one file be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be a good solution for code comprehension. Slim is a micro-framework, so there is no real file structure, this leaves you free to do almost as you want.

You can read [this article](http://www.slimframework.com/2011/09/24/how-to-organize-a-large-slim-framework-application.html) for more informations about how to organize your Slim file structure.

Answer (score 1):

I take a similar approach but using `group`:

`index.php`

```
require '../Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();
$app = new \Slim\Slim();

require 'routes/articles.php';
$app->run();
```

`routes/articles.php`

```
$app->group('/articles', function () use ($app) {

  $app->get('/:foo', function($foo) use ($app) {
     ...
  });

  $app->get('/:foo/:bar', function($foo, $bar) use ($app) {
     echo 'Info about all routes';
  });
```

});